# Achar o ID das Conversas do whatsapp web no html

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Olá, sou {INICIANTE} e estou fazendo uma extensao como projeto pessoal e aprendendo no processo, mas tenho um problema:

A extensao serve para o whatsapp web, ela por exemplo precisa, ao eu abrir uma conversa, ela pergar o id dessa conversa, e exibir por exemplo os dados daquele contato aberto (numero, nome salvo...) e aparecer determinado dado para aquele UNICO contato na janela da minha extensao, vamos dizer uma mensagem ["Ola marcio" - numero: 00 99999-9999" contato: marcio alves], entao quando eu abrir outro contato, identificar como outra pessoa e exibir outros dados ["Vamos jogar futebol" - numero: 00 88888-8888" contato: diego], so que o problema é que lendo,ou tentando o html do wpp web, as conversas estao em uma lista, mas na acho nada que possa ser usado como um identificador unico.

COMO CRIAR OU ACHAR O ID ( IDENTIFICADOR UNICO ) DAS CONVERSAS DO WHASTAPP? DE CADA CONTATO PARA QUE MINHA EXTENSAO POSSA DIFERENCIAR CADA UM E EMITIR NA TELA DA EXTESAO O DADO CERTO E DEFINIDO PARA AQUELE CONTATO?

Para cada id/contato

ID: 2787 (numero: 00 88888-8888, contato: diego) ID: 1782 (numero: 00 99999-9999" contato: marcio)

Nao sei se deu pra entender tudo, mas ficaria grato se pudessem me ajudar.

Comment: Essa pergunta já foi feita aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/592961/137387 e se encontra fechada por conta da baixa qualidade. Por favor evite o flood e bloqueios de publicação siga as instruções não repetindo perguntas e seguindo as orientações fornecidas no campo de comentários da publicação original.